# How to terminate BCP output with specific string AND newline?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to terminate each row in BCP output with a specific string along with newline. Neither of these work:

- -r"terminator_string\n"';
- -r"terminator_string"+\n';

Any suggestions?

For an idea of the overall problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329028/outofmemory-exception-when-reading-and-replacing-strings-with-streamreader-and-s

Comment: Could you provide more detail on what you want compared to what you are getting? Are the apostrophe and semi-colon part of the code? With `-c -r "test\n"` I'm getting what I think you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ASCII codes of the characters you want to match (without the 0x prefix).

For example to match A (char hex 41) + LineFeed (char hex 0A) do this:

`-r "410A"`

This seems to be undocumented. See my blog here for more info: http://kejser.org/databases/bulk-insert-with-linux-line-endings/

Answer (score 0):

Check [Specifying Field and Row Terminators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for bcp

E.g.:

> -r \n -Specifies the row terminator as a newline character. This is
>   the default row terminator, so specifying it is optional.

Hope this helps