# Use non-printable characters in SQL Server BCP xml format file as TERMINATOR

Tags: sql-server, xml, encoding, bcp

I have a flat-text data file containing records which fields are separated by the non printable character ["File Separator" (0x1c)](https://numbermonk.com/hexadecimal/28/en). I am trying to use SQL Server's bcp utility to load this data into my database. Yet, when using the hex encoded value of the File Separator as TERMINATOR, I get a syntax error.

I have tried using

- the hex encoded value : `"0x1c"`
- the XML encoded value as hex: `"&#x1c;"`
- the XML encoded value as decimal: `"&#28;"`

None of these work, yet when using the same encoding for a printable character, like `tab`, this does work: `&#x09;`, `&#9;` (`0x9` doesn't. Not unsurprisingly, since this is an XML file.)

The conclusion seems to be that non-printable characters are not supported. Is this the case? That would be ironical, since the non-printable separator characters are created exactly for this purpose...

Below you can find all code to reproduce this issue:

**XML format file: test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="&#x1c;" MAX_LENGTH="10" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CS_AS_WS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="41"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="COL1" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="COL2" xsi:type="SQLNUMERIC" PRECISION="4" SCALE="0"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

**Data file: test.txt**
This is just one row, as a test case. StackExchange doesn't show the separator in the row below, yet when you click "Edit" for this post, the separator is included, and you should be able to copy-paste this.

```
1111111112008
```

**Commandline**

```
bcp TEST_DB.dbo.UL_TEST in "test.txt" -T -f "test.xml"
```

Comment: Weird, because [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/xml-format-files-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#AttrOfFieldElement) states `This attribute specifies the terminator of a data field. The terminator can be any character.`

Comment: Maybe this could work? https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/64413/65699. The answer is for non-XML format files though.

Comment: @TT : Thanks for the suggestion. I've tested this, and it doesn't work for XML format files. i've also tested with normal printable characters, and with 2 characters per the example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *seems*, from the documentation about [BCP - Specify Field and Row Terminators (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), that non-printable characters are not supported:

> **Characters Supported As Terminators**
>
> The bcp command, BULK INSERT statement, and the OPENROWSET bulk rowset
>   provider support a variety of characters as field or row terminators
>   and always look for the first instance of each terminator. The
>   following table lists the supported characters for terminators.

[image]

As an option, you could use `POWERSHELL` to read in the source file and search\replace the `0x1C` characters with some other character like a tilda (~) and output to a different file.  Then use that character as your terminator.

```
(Get-Content c:\test\test.txt) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace [char]0x1C,'~'} | Set-Content c:\test\testout.txt
```

Comment: How arbitrary... Printable characters only, for something that has nothing to do with printing?

Comment: @Scott Hodgin : The documentation indeed implies that non-printable characters can't be used. It's weird, it sucks, and it should be fixed, but still this is a valid answer to the question :) Thanks

Comment: Thx for the powershell. In the meantime I had already worked out something similar, yet slightly more elaborate. Posted it as a separate answer.

Comment: After some testing, I've figured out that only printable ASCII characters are supported. So, up to HEX 0->127. Any other characters in the cp1252 set, like €, is not supported. Also any other UTF8 character is not supported.

Comment: @Wouter - yeah, bummer!  Glad you solved it another way :)

Answer (score 1):

Since @ScottHodgin pointed out that non-printable characters are not supported, replacing them in the source file is the only alternative.

Below you can find an example PowerShell script that can make this replacement on a file encoded in UTF8(with or without BOM header doesn't matter), and writes an output file encoded in UTF8 without a BOM header.

Additionally, it uses AppendAllLines to turn this into a streaming operation. This way it also works for huge files, since they don't have to be entirely loaded into memory before doing the replacements. -ReadCount 1000 speeds up the process drastically.

```
$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 -ReadCount 1000 test.txt |
     Foreach-Object { 
        [System.IO.File]::AppendAllLines(
              [string]'test.txt'
            , [string[]]($_ -replace '\x1C', '')
            , $Utf8NoBomEncoding
        ) 
    }
```

Make sure you save the script above in a file that is encoded with UTF8 **with** BOM header, otherwise PowerShell doesn't process the characters as UTF-8.